# Android - Prevent Clipping of Button Text Inside HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I have a HorizontalScrollView at the bottom of an app, and I want each button inside to be equal width, but not clip button text. I've tried playing around with "layout_width" of LinearLayouts, HorizontalScrollView and Buttons, as well as changing button weights.

I end up with either: 4 buttons exactly filling the screen width (which is NOT what I want, since the user needs to realize  additional buttons are available), or the screenshot below (button text clipped).

How can I have equal button widths, no text clipped and one button partially shown to indicate scrolling is possible?

[image]

**my_activity.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/my_layout"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
      <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="6"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/my_style_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/my_color"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_color"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/my_behavior_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/my_behavior"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_behavior"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/sound_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/sound"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_sound"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/my_background_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/my_background"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_background"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/share_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/social_share"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_social_share"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/about_button"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/about"
              android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_about"
              style="@style/Toolbar_Button"
              android:drawablePadding="10dp"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/ListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ListViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
  </style>
  <style name="TextAppearance_Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
  </style>
  <style name="Toolbar_Button" parent="android:Widget">
      <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_button</item>   
  </style>
</resources>
```

**toolbar_button.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
  <corners
  android:radius="10dp"
/>
  <solid
  android:color="#FFFFFF"
/>
  <padding
  android:left="10dp"
  android:top="10dp"
  android:right="10dp"
  android:bottom="10dp"
/>

  <stroke
  android:width="3dp"
  android:color="#878787"
/>
</shape>
```

Comment: @user3678528 Where?

Comment: Try   
android:layout_width="0dp"
Instead of  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 
for all button.

Comment: @user3678528 I tried your suggestion, but the result was the same (text clipped on each button).